# Android studio .XML confusion with the book that is teaching me android development

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have just started my android journey with the help of a book. Which is not recommended but it is my preferred method of learning. In this book when I get to examine the layout file `.xml` the book says that this pre-made file starts and ends with

```
<RelativeLayout> ... </RelativeLayout>
```

but in the android manifest file I was given, I noticed the contents were similar but started and ended with a

```
<manifest> ... </manifest>
```

so are these two pieces of code the same, are they interchangeable, how can this confuse me in the future, and can this *Error* make the book I am using obsolete. (The book is called "Android Programming for Beginners" by John Horton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xml is a file type, and is used for several things in Android development.

The AndroidManifest.xml file is the App's configuration xml file.
It describes essential information about your app to the Android build tools, the Android operating system, and Google Play.
It's used also to declare:

- The app's package name, which usually matches your code's namespace
- the components of the app, which include all activities, services, broadcast receivers and content providers
- ....
  and Many more...

The Layout files (.xml files also) are used to create the designs, you can use several tags according to your need inside those design.xml files:

Examples of Android xml design tags:

```
<RelativeLayout ... </RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout ... </LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout ... </FrameLayout>
<ScrollView ... </ScrollView>
<TextView ... </TextView>
<ImageView ... </ImageView>
```

And many more...

They are two different xml file so they are not interchangeable

Regarding the book:
I checked it, it's very good, but i think if you start with video tutorial first then go back to the book after 2 weeks you're gonna save a lot of time later and you will be able to understand the book better.

Keep learning, Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the good luck, but can you recommend any channels or videos in particular. As i feel that most video tutorials temd to get outdated and confusing very quickly.

Comment: You're 100% right, you have to know which videos you watch & which book you read. The most important thing is the release date.
you can check this 2019 new video for beginners:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuGkXg4PjKU

Comment: You can check also the lynda.com tutorials for android (it's not free, but you can get a free month if you have a linkedIn.com account), plz always check the release date of the tutorial & make sure it's not older than 1 year.
If you are interested in Kotlin (alternative of Java for Android Development) check this one (you can start a membership with 1 free month)
https://www.lynda.com/Android-tutorials/Android-Development-Essential-Training-Create-Your-First-App/751324-2.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. And as for the Java or Kotlin, i am trying to keep my options (somewhat) open because i may continue to making more than android apps, and i want my first programming language to be something versatile.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not the same. 
You can read more about the Android Manifest file [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro), but it is basically a file which describes essential information about your app to the Android build tools, the Android operating system, and Google Play.

The `.xml` file, which starts with

```
<RelativeLayout> ... </RelativeLayout>
```

is for building the frontend in Android. You can read more about this topic [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui).